# How to get the 'msa' package to work with all characters

Tags: r

I'd like to use R's 'msa' package to align multiple sentences, all of which are slight variants on an original.

The sentence contains a number of special characters, e.g.

```
Š, Ú, $, etc.
```

Which I'd like to preserve.  Is there any way of getting 'msa' to accept these characters?

Previously I tried the `align_local` function, but I don't think it's written to handle multiple sequences.

Comment: Need a reproducible example. Read [MCVE]

Comment: Please provide example data, code, and the expected output.

Comment: Example data, code, and the expected output?  Will that really help?  I'd like É.{ḫ}š-š⸢Ú⸣ and É.{š}ḫ-š⸢Ú⸣ to be aligned so they differ by the /š/ and /ḫ/ rather than just getting ?????????? because none of the characters are recognised.